# Making custom routing changes permanent in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, networking, routing, centos-7, iproute2

I need to make some custom routing commands be maintained whenever the main LAN network interface is restarted/system rebooted.

I've been reading how to do this in CentOS 7 and accordingly to documentation you need to use a `route-[interface_name]` file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`. However the format is slightly different from using the raw route commands:

```
ip -f inet rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip -f inet route add local default dev eno1 table 100

ip -f inet6 rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip -f inet6 route add local default dev eno1 table 100
```

What is the correct way to write these route commands in a route script that works with CentOS 7 so the route information is kept in the routing table?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a file and add the rules, but I recommend you to use the 'nmcli' command. It's new in Red Hat 7 / CentOS 7.

The 'nmcli' command automatically updates the files, and it makes changes persistent across reboots.

```
# man nmcli-examples
# nmcli con add help
```

After you finish making changes run:

```
# nmcli con reload
# nmcli con down <interface name>
# nmcli con up <interface name>
```